# How to pass variable into init in a JavaScript program

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a model named user.js that uses Sequelize:

```
const { Sequelize, Model, STRING,} = require('sequelize');

var sequelizeCredentials = null;

class User extends Model{
    constructor(sequelizeCredentials){
        this.sequelizeCredentials = sequelizeCredentials;
    }
};
console.log(sequelizeCredentials);
User.init(
    {
        id: {type:Sequelize.UUID, defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4, primaryKey:true},
        username: {type:STRING, allowNull:false},
        password: {type:STRING, allowNull:false},
        name: {type:STRING, allowNull:false},
    },{sequelize: sequelizeCredentials, modelName:'user'}
);
module.exports = { User };
```

I am trying to pass my sequelize credentials from the app.js like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const user = require('./modals/user');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

initialize();
async function initialize() {
   const sequelize = new Sequelize(
        'express_project',
        'root',
        '',
        {
            dialect: 'mysql'
        }
    );

    localUser = new user.User(sequelize);

    await sequelize.sync();
}
```

However, I keep getting an error saying "No Sequelize instance passed".

I am very new to JS/TS.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
const { Sequelize, Model, STRING,} = require('sequelize');

class User extends Model{
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
  static init(sequelize) {
   return super.init({
     id: {type:Sequelize.UUID, defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4, primaryKey:true},
     username: {type:STRING, allowNull:false},
     password: {type:STRING, allowNull:false},
     name: {type:STRING, allowNull:false},
    },{sequelize, modelName:'user'});
   }
}
module.exports = { User };
```

in app.js

```
async function initialize() {
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    'express_project',
    'root',
    '',
    {
        dialect: 'mysql'
    }
);

User.init(sequelize);

await sequelize.sync();
```

}

more od es6 classes with sequlize check this out https://codewithhugo.com/using-es6-classes-for-sequelize-4-models/

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying so many other methods but they didnt work.

Comment: Can I ask how do I access the properties within the super.init? like if i want to get User.id

Comment: init is a static method at the class level the id is a instance property, you have define instance methods(see the link on es6 classes) where you will can access id e.g this.id , can you please describe what exactly you are trying to achieve?